# I can't access to inner data of my object in js

Tags: javascript, json, object

In my online shop I want to add client order by item to orders.
First I click and add an Item from db.
Then I pass chosen item to js.

```
$('#addItem').click(function () {
   let itemData = $('#item').val();

   console.log(itemData);
});
```

this is output:

```
{"id":1,"business_id":401,"name":"\u067e\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0647\u0646","discount_model":1,"special_date":0,"hot_offer":0,"percent":30,"buy_quantity":null,"prize_quantity":null,"prize_name":null,"floor_buy":null,"discount_percent":null,"is_active":1,"created_at":"2019-07-02 06:43:23","updated_at":"2019-07-02 06:44:51"}
```

now I want itemData.name or itemData['name'], but it says: undefined !?

How can I access to props?

Comment: Anything from [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) will be a string. If that string is JSON, you need to parse it first, ie `let itemData = JSON.parse($('#item').val())`

Comment: Just check `typeof itemData` you will know the reason for error

Comment: _"this is output:"_  I bet it's not. I imagine it's more like `"{"id":1,"business_id":401,...}"` where the whole thing is wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can't call properties from string, you have to convert the String to JSON object, The below `parse` method can do it.

```
itemData = JSON.parse(itemData)
```

Refer simple example :

```js
var myJsonStr = '{"id":1,"business_id":401,"name":"\u067e\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0647\u0646","discount_model":1,"special_date":0,"hot_offer":0,"percent":30,"buy_quantity":null,"prize_quantity":null,"prize_name":null,"floor_buy":null,"discount_percent":null,"is_active":1,"created_at":"2019-07-02 06:43:23","updated_at":"2019-07-02 06:44:51"}';

var myJson = JSON.parse(myJsonStr);

console.log(myJson.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$('#addItem').click(function () {
  let itemData = $('#item').val();
  try {
    itemData = JSON.parse(itemData);
  } catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }

  console.log(itemData.name);
});
```

Comment: Why bother with `try..catch` if you're just going to throw the error anyway?

Comment: @Phil I just implemented try catch block. It depends on the person who will implement it. Personally, I'll implement a logger here.

Answer (score -3):

tldr; safely access nested objects in JavaScript in a super cool way.

Most of the times when we’re working with JavaScript, we’ll be dealing with nested objects and often we’ll be needing to access the innermost nested values safely.

Let’s take this nested object as an example.

const user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: {
            line1: 'westwish st',
            line2: 'washmasher',
            city: 'wallas',
            state: 'WX'
        }
    }
}

To access the name of the our user, we’ll write

const name = user.personalInfo.name;
const userCity = user.personalInfo.address.city;